# Struct field not updated when implementing interface function

Tags: interface, go

If for example we have the following interface:

```
type IRoute interface {
    AddChildren(child IRoute)
}
```

The following struct:

```
type Route struct {
    Alias string `json:"alias"`
    Children []Route `json:"children,omitempty"`
    Url string `json:"url,omitempty"`
}
```

And implemented the interface:

```
func (this Route) AddChildren (child globals.IRoute){
    this.Children = append(this.Children, child.(Route))
}
```

Then in our main func, if we wanted to test this it would not work:

```
rSettings := Route{"settings", nil, "/admin/settings"}
rSettingsContentTypesNew := models.Route{"new", nil, "/new?type&parent"}
rSettingsContentTypesEdit := models.Route{"edit", nil, "/edit/:nodeId"}

// Does NOT work - no children is added
rSettingsContentTypes.AddChildren(rSettingsContentTypesNew)
rSettingsContentTypes.AddChildren(rSettingsContentTypesEdit)
rSettings.AddChildren(rSettingsContentTypes)
```

And this does work as expected:

```
rSettings := Route{"settings", nil, "/admin/settings"}
rSettingsContentTypesNew := models.Route{"new", nil, "/new?type&parent"}
rSettingsContentTypesEdit := models.Route{"edit", nil, "/edit/:nodeId"}

// However this does indeed work
rSettingsContentTypes.Children = append(rSettingsContentTypes.Children,rSettingsContentTypesNew)
rSettingsContentTypes.Children = append(rSettingsContentTypes.Children,rSettingsContentTypesEdit)
rSettings.Children = append(rSettings.Children,rSettingsContentTypes)
```

What am I missing? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The receiver of `func (this Route) AddChildren (child globals.IRoute)` is a value, so you are changing a copy of your `Route` struct.

Change it to `func (this *Route) AddChildren (child globals.IRoute)`

Comment: Happy I could help. Here is a little further reading: http://golang.org/doc/faq#Pointers and for this specific question http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers